# Pause application then F10 turn into step by step debugging code VS-2017

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

Before Visual Studio 2017, I can pause the application then pressing F10/F11, turn the execution into step by step code debugging and execution, but in visual studio 2017 it will not do that. How can i turn it on?

Comment: If you select the **Debug** menu from the menu bar, what options do you see? Does **Step Into** and **Step Over** not show up anymore? Can you provide a screenshot of your Tools Menu?

Comment: Hi, does this issue persists for any project types or just the specific project? Please have a try with 1. Make sure all third party software is closed, 2.go to Tools-Import and Export settings-Reset all settings and choose ‘General Development settings’ to reset

Answer (score 1):

On the question written as it currently states, it looks as if your keyboard shortcuts were either modified or disabled. To reset this:

1. In the menu bar, select **Tools > Options...**
2. In the left window pane select **Environment > Keyboard**
3. Select a mapping scheme of your choice from the drop-down (for example, I use Visual C# 2005 because I just like the convenience of their shortcut key combinations). If your scheme is already selected, click the **Reset** button instead.
4. Click **OK**

Your shortcuts should be reset to normal.

Comment: That's works.... Thanks a lot.